# Probability of missiles on target

Tags: probability, statistics

The captain of a Navy gunboat orders a volley of 25 missiles to be fired at random along a five-hundred-foot stretch of shoreline that he hopes to establish as a beachhead. Dug into the beach is a thirty-foot-long bunker serving as the enemy's first line of defense. The captain has reason to believe that the bunker will be destroyed if at least three of the missiles are on-target. What is the probability of that happening?

This is how I would start. successes=missiles hitting bunker, $n=25$, $p= 30/500=.06$, $1-p=.94$, $k=3$ through 25. Can someone help me with the rest?

Comment: use the binomial distribution?

Comment: so would it just be $$ \binom{25}{3} * .06^3 * .94^{22} = .13 $$

can someone concur

Comment: @notamathwiz: that is the probability exactly three hit.  But you also want to count four hitting and five and ...

Comment: That is a good start, you need at least 3 bombs, so 4,5,6... 25 is also okay. so you just add these numbers. However, a faster way of doing it would be 1-prob(no bomb hit)-prob(1 bomb hit) - prob (2 bomb hit)

Comment: so i have to use summation from 3 hitting the target to all 25 hitting the target, is there a easy was of doing the summation with out having to evaluate each one separably? and with out using integration since i do not know how to take the integral of a choose notation?

Comment: No, there is no "simple" formula for the sum you need.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate the sum, note that for a binomial distribution

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} = 1$$

Therefore, when $K$ is the number of hits,

$$\begin{align}P(K \ge 3) &= \sum_{k=3}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\\ &= 1-P(K=0)-P(K=1)-P(K=2)\\ &= 1-\binom{25}{0} (0.06)^0 (0.94)^{25} - \binom{25}{1} (0.06)^1 (0.94)^{24} - \binom{25}{2} (0.06)^2 (0.94)^{23}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability $k$ hit out of $n$ is $${n \choose k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

so substitute and add up, or to save time calculate the probability that not enough hit.